# Error in Visual Studio 2010 ISO Installation

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I try to install VS 2010 ISO.

First step (installing) **setup.exe** is succes, but when I continue with **vs_setup.msci**, it always cancelled in the middle of process.

Anyone know whats really happen and what should I do to fix this issue?

I use 32-bit and installing TFX-x86

Always stop after this process:

**"Please wait while Windows configures Microsoft Team Foundation Server 2010 - ENU ..."**

[image: stop after this process]

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Usually this sort of things happen, when some software was set up incorrectly and installing package is depending on it. Try this approaches to localize problem source:

1. Try using Windows Installer Cleanup utility before TFS installation. Its pretty old and no longer supported, so use it with caution.
2. Open up Windows Event Viever (`eventvwr.msc`), Windows Logs, Application. Filter events from `MsiInstaller`

   [image]

Check log for error and warning messages, especially warnings like that:

> Event Type: Warning Event Source: MsiInstaller Event ID: 1001
>   Description: Detection of product
>   '{000C1109-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}', feature 'Example' failed
>   during request for component '{00030829-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}'

GUIDs of course would be different. To determine product and component, open registry editor (`regedit`) and look up key `HKLM\Software\Classes\Installer`.
Product/component GUIDs are written without dashes and each GUID part is reversed (`000C1109` would be `9011C000` and so on).
This will allow you to understand which component prevents TFS installation and reinstall it.

3. Clean windows reinstall is also an option if anything else fails.